# knitr2pdf eclipse : how to configure?

Tags: r, eclipse, knitr

I'm trying to set up eclipse to build my document following this tutorial https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/eclipse/, so I have set up eclipse accordingly

[image: eclipse output]

When trying to run the program I get into the following error

> knit2pdf(file= "C:/workspace/p/example_scripts/test_knit2pdf.Rmd")
>   Error in readLines(if (is.character(input2)) { :    object 'input2' 
>   not found

When trying to find something about that error, I found this post which only explains that there might be a fix in markdown. 
https://github.com/andrewheiss/SublimeKnitr/issues/7
Could someone give me a hint on how to solve that problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not following the documentation https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/eclipse/. The function `knitr::knit2pdf()` does not have an argument named `file`. Either use `input=` or just leave out the argument name (i.e. use positional arguments).